# PHP - Accessing a value selected in Combobox

Tags: php, post, combobox

I want to write a code that should let me select from a drop down list and onClick of a button load the data from a mysql database.However I cannot access the value selected in the drop down menu.I have tried to access them by `$_POST['var_name']` but still can't do it.

I'm new to PHP.

Following is my code:

```
 <?php

      function load(){
       $department = $_POST['dept'];
       $employee = $_POST['emp'];

       //echo "$department";
       //echo "$employee";

       $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd", "payroll");
       $rs = $con->query("select * from dept where deptno='$department'");
       $row = $rs->fetch_row();
       $n = $row[0];
       $rs->free();
       $con->close();
      }

 ?>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Payroll</title>
     </head>

     <body>
      <h1 align="center">IIT Department</h1>
      <form method="post">
      <table align="center">
       <tr>
        <td>
          Dept Number: 
          <select name="dept">
               <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
               <option value="20">20</option>
               <option value="30">30</option>
               <option value="40">40</option>
          </select>


            </td>

        <td>
             <input type="button" value="ShowDeptEmp" name="btn1">        
        </td>
        <td>
          Job: 
          <select name="job">
               <option value="President" selected="selected">President</option>
               <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
               <option value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
               <option value="Salesman">Salesman</option>
               <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="button" value="ShowJobEmp" name="btn1">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
        <?php if(isset($_POST['dept']) && $_POST['dept'] != "") load();  ?>        
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks +1 but I guess there are some more mistakes ..

Comment: Bah, there is a huge injection vulnerability there. If you're going to use MySQLi, you should atleast prepare and bind_param the statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change button to submit

```
 <input type="submit" value="ShowDeptEmp" name="btn1">
```

and

```
 <input type="submit" value="ShowJobEmp" name="btn2">
```

Comment: I changed it to:  <input type="submit" value="ShowDeptEmp" name="btn1" onClick="<?php if(isset($_POST['dept']) && $_POST['dept'] != ''){load();} ?>" >

Comment: @Pavitar: no need to use onClick event type submit will automatically submit page when you click on btn

Comment: +1 ok now I am able to echo $department.but my query still doesn't fire :(

Comment: @Pavitar: use mysqli_connect('.', "root", "pwd", "payroll", null, 'mysql'); or $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pwd', 'payroll');

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of echoing `$department` into your SQL.  If someone posted `'; DROP TABLE dept;` they could run arbitrary SQL commands (See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

OR you can use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when escaping `$department` if you don't want to use a Prepared Statement.

Comment: This is just the first time I have tried to code in php. I just want to know how to access values from my combobox. Later on I will implement all what you have said to avoid injection. Please help me on how to access the values,because in my code $department is not being echoed.